# Global variable with initialization callback

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I use a third-party module ([a spell-checker](https://github.com/mrmarbles/wordsworth)) that has a long initialization process, and calls a callback after the initialization is complete.

I need to use this module in several different files (sub-modules) of my application.

It looks like a waste of time and space to initialize a different spell-checker in each sub-modules, so I am looking for a way to initialize a single spell-checker and use it in all modules.

One option I thought of is to put a spell-checker instance in a sub-module, initialize it in the sub-module, and require that sub-module from my other sub-modules. But, I don't know how to deal with the initialization callback - how can I make sure that my other sub-modules won't use the spell-checker instance before it is initialized?

Another option I thought of is to create a separate application that with the spell-checker, and contact it from my application via TCP/IP or another mechanism. But this also looks wasteful - too much communication overhead.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

This is analogous to using a database driver library and waiting for it to connect successfully to the database before issuing queries. The most prevalent pattern seems to be for the asynchronous library to emit an event such as 'connected' and the calling code to not start interacting with the library until that event fires. The other option would be to follow the example of something like mongoose and queue bending calls until the spell checker is initialized and then begin submitting them for processing.

So in short I would wrap the spell checking in a small library that exports the spell checker directly, but also emits a 'ready' event when the underlying spellchecker library invokes the initialization callback. It should be possible to share this same instance of the wrapper module throughout your application.

Answer (score 1):

Create your own module, `checker.js`, where

```
var spellChecker = require('wordsworth').getInstance();
var initialized = false;

module.exports = function (callback) {
  if (!initialized) {
    return spellChecker.initialize(/* data */, function () {
      initialized = true;
      callback (spellChecker);
    }
  }

  callback (spellChecker);
}
```

client.js

```
var checker = require('./checker);
checker(function (spellChecker) {
   // use it..
});
```

So, it will be initialized on first call, the rest of clients will use initialized version.